# Xamarin.Forms - Building IOS Failed to resolve Xamarin.Forms.Font

Tags: ios, build, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms solution and I am getting the below error when attempting to build my IOS project from Visual Studio.

```
Error   4   Failed to resolve "Xamarin.Forms.Font Xamarin.Forms.Font::WithAttributes(Xamarin.Forms.FontAttributes)" reference from "Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=1.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"  Score_Capture.iOS
```

I have done the following including troubleshooting and build host diagnostics but I'm not sure what the problem is or how to proceed:

- My build host has been setup and paired to visual studio, viewing the MAC server log I can confirm successful communication
- My Iphone has been provisioned
- Manual certificates added to the keychain
- I have updated the Xamarin.Forms Nuget packages to the latest version

### System Information:

- XCode Version 6.1
- Visual Studio 2013 Professional V 12.0.305 Update 2
- Xamarin.Forms V1.2.2.6243 (Android)
- Xamarin.Forms V1.2.3.6257 (IOS)

Comment: Why are you using different versions of Forms in Android and iOS?  They should match.

Answer (score 0):

The `Failed to resolve` probably means you're either missing a reference or you have an ambiguous reference to Xamarin.Forms.FontAttributes enum.

First, what version of Xamarin.Forms.Core are you using? If it's an earlier version, it might not support FontAttributes. Last I checked, 1.2.3.6257 is the latest (looks like you're using it for iOS but not Android.. I would fix that, as Jason suggested, but ALSO make sure you have the latest version for the core).

If you're good on versioning and the problem persists, I would check your Project.iOS references in the solution explorer to ensure that `Xamarin.Forms.Core` is included. Also make sure you're `using Xamarin.Forms;` at the top of your files.

If it's not a versioning issue and you do indeed have all the correct references, I would recommend tracking down where you're setting your font attributes and explicitly stating `Xamarin.Forms.FontAttributes.Italic` or whatever attribute you're trying to use. I don't think that `FontAttributes` should be ambiguous but who knows.